# Nginx proxy_pass exclude url with regex

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm trying to proxy pass a location excluding only a casistic with a regex.

I have this url `/autocomplete/<var1>/<var2>` and I want to proxy pass only if `var1` is different from `a`, so `b/foo`, `c/foo` ecc will be proxied.

In apache I used this:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/autocomplete/a/(.*)$ !
ProxyPass /autocomplete/ http://localhost:1234/autocomplete/
```

In NGINX I tried with this:

```
location ~ /autocomplete/(?<var1>.*)/(?<var2>.*) {
    if ($var1 != "a") {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234/autocomplete/$var1/$var2;
   }
}
```

It works for other values of `var1`, but for `a` it returns 404.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
location ~ ^/autocomplete/(?!(a)) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
}
```